# Right naming of confusion matrix in scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

Lets asumme I have the following test values:

```
y_test2 = [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

and the following prediction values:

```
y_pred2 = [1, 0, 1, 1]
```

So I have a binary classificaiton problem with `{0,1}`as classes.
If i am using sklearn `confusion_matrix`:

```
confusion_matrix(y_test2, y_pred2)
array([[1, 1], #one 0 was predicted as 0 (TruePositive),  one 0 was predicted as 1 (FalseNegative)
       [0, 2]], dtype=int64) #two 1 were predicted as 1 (TrueNegatives)
```

So for me it is:

```
TP: 1
FN: 1
TN: 2
FP: 0
```

However, when I run the confusion_matrix with ravel, followed scikit learns documentation:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test2, y_pred2).ravel()
(1, 1, 0, 2)
```

Why is scikit interpretating the 1 as True values? And why is it not mentioned in the docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html
Is there any other issue I could face for binary classification with the naming convention? Is there any chance to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the description in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html):

> Thus in binary classification, the count of true negatives is C(0,0) , false negatives is C(1,0), true positives is  C(1,1) and false positives is C(0,1) .

so from you array

```
array([[1, 1], 
       [0, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

it is

```
TN: 1
FN: 0
TP: 2
FP: 1
```